# Haskell list index out of bounds

Tags: haskell

How can I modify the below function such that the case when the list is shorter than the index searched  will result in an error.

```
elementAt::Int -> [Int] -> Int
elementAt = Data.Foldable.foldl (\x y -> if x == 0 then y else x-1)
```

1 is the index of the first element

Comment: I think this function is wrong, even if you try to get an element in the range of the list. For example, `elementAt 0 [1, 2, 3]` will return `3`.

Comment: I believe explicit recursion is easier to use in this case than folds.

Comment: 1 is considered the index element I forgot to mention thus 0 is considered out of bounds either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a fold to find the n-th element in a list is a pretty difficult way. I want to present you an easier way using explicit recursion:

You have to look at this problem differently:

1. What is my base case?
2. How should the recursive call look like?
3. (Optional) What about errors?

The method's type signature is given:

```
elementAt :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
```

Only worrying about the first point, we know that if the index is `0`, we want to return that element:

```
elementAt 1 (x:_) = x
```

Now what if our number is greater than `1`? In this case we want to decrement our index end test the predicate for the next item:

```
elementAt n (x:xs) = elementAt (n-1) xs
```

Now we are almost done! If we want to throw an error if the element in the specified position is not found, we can simply use `error`:

```
elementAt _ _ = error "Element not found!"
```

But this is not how the idiomatic Haskell way works. One possible solution is to use a `Maybe` to wrap the result in. For this we have to change the type signature a little bit:

```
elementAt :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
```

Now the function is able to return `Just` the element at the specified position if it exists and `Nothing` otherwise:

```
elementAt 1 (x:_)  = Just x
elementAt n (x:xs) = elementAt (n-1) xs
elementAt _ _      = Nothing
```

---

For the sake of completeness, here one possible way to achieve this though a fold:

```
elementAt n = foldl (\acc x -> if fst x == n then snd x else acc) n . zip [1..n]
```

Comment: Seems a good answer, I tought there is a shorter method of doing this, thanks!

Comment: @CosminMihai There is a shorter method of doing this but I can promise you that it is not nearly as easy to implement/read.

Comment: It does not matter, that was the purpose of the question, to find a shorter way of doing this, if you know a better way, share it please

Comment: `elementAt n xs = xs!!n`  -- for 0 based index, decrement n by one for 1 based index.

Comment: @karakfa Sure, but the question implied that an own implementation had to be written IMO

Comment: That last implementation can be greatly improved by using `. zip [0 .. n-1]`. But also I see the OP now wants 1-indexed lists, so some other things need to change if you care.